# Combine rows of a dataframe on ID to sum values, but keep categorical data

Tags: python, pandas

I’m cleaning data and had a question. I have a Contact dataset and an Account dataset. I need to merge the two dataframes on “ContactID”. Some ContactID’s have multiple accounts. So, when I merge them there are still some ContactID’s that have multiple rows. I need to combine these rows so that the numeric columns add together, while still keeping the categorical columns. Below is an example:

When I merge:

```
ContactID           Value                  Type
1                           800                      A
1                           70                        A
2                           100                      B
3                           300                      A
4                           200                      C
5                           500                      B
5                           600                      B
```

What I need the data to look like when I merge:

```
ContactID           Value                  Type
1                           870                      A
2                           100                      B
3                           300                      A
4                           200                      C
5                           1100                    B
```

I have tried this:

```py
fulldf.groupby(fulldf.ContactID).sum()
```

But, then I only get a dataframe that contains numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

Let us check with `dtype` and create the `groupby` `dict`

```
out = df.groupby('ContactID').agg(df.dtypes.map({'O':'first'}).fillna('sum').to_dict())
           ContactID  Value Type
ContactID                       
1                  2    870    A
2                  2    100    B
3                  3    300    A
4                  4    200    C
5                 10   1100    B
```

Comment: Now, that is cool method, using `df.dtypes` and `map`.   I learn something new today. I will use this in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After grouping you can apply individual aggregation functions to the columns of the DataFrame. For the numeric column use the sum, for the categorical column take the first element.

```
df.groupby("ContactID").agg(
    {
        "Value": lambda col: col.sum(),
        "Type": lambda col: col.iloc[0],
    }
)

# Output
ContactID   Value   Type
1           870     A
2           100     B
3           300     A
4           200     C
5           1100    B
```